# View the content of a .bat file through command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch, cmd.exe

I want to scan the whole desktop for .bat and then view the .bat file's content and delete the file if it includes **ipconfig** for a project. Is there any way I can do it? I'd like to **NOT** use third party tools

Comment: Why don't you just open the file with Notepad?  You can just use "cat filename" within a PowerShell prompt.

Comment: it doesnt work i tried it on test.bat which had the code "echo test123" and it showed some broken characters

Comment: You can use `type` to spit out the file content to the prompt.

Comment: that works but how can it detect wheter it has ipconfig or no?

Comment: `find /i "ipconfig" file.bat && del file.bat`

Comment: @Stephan That is a proper answer. Why don't you make it into one.

Comment: @Stephan that works! I'd accept it as an answer btw that's off-topic but can I detect wheter there is bat files on the desktop and try finding ipconfig in each one?

Comment: ***TheCodeExpert*** is a funny name given the question you are asking.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas yeah but lets just not chat... and if you **KNOW** the answer please share

Comment: Your question says you know nothing or very little about PowerShell. As this is a day one learning thing. Plety of examples all over the web and via Youtube.

This is not a PowerShell issue or specific feaqture. You can do this in cmd.exe just a easily or any other scripting language.

You learn by doing one thing at a time, then putting it together. Not asking others to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Powershell script below gets the content of the file `myfile.bat`, check if the string `ipconfig` is present. If yes, the file is deleted.

```ps
$file = 'c:\temp\myfile.bat`
$a = Get-Content $file | Select-String ipconfig
if( $a.Length -gt 0){Remove-Item $file}
```

To include a folder for example your Desktop, change the script as shown below. Replace `mthecodeexpert` with your real username.

```ps
$folder = 'c:\users\thecodeexpert\*.bat'
$files = Get-ChildItem $folder -file
$files | ForEach-Object{ $a = Select-String -Path $_.Fullname ipconfig; if ($a.Length -gt 0){Remove-Item $_.Fullname}}
```

Comment: this works but not as I wanted. It needs to check the desktop for *.bat's and then do this...

Comment: Please expand this answer with the function to search for batch files at a given location.  Yes, I *could* do it but it is your answer and beats the cmd.exe method (IMHO).. and yes, I love batch too.. but powershell is usually a better tool when it comes to grepping files.  Your answer can even be used on non MS operating systems.

Comment: `select-string` already grabs the contents from files

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas See edit.

Comment: @TheCodeExpert See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment...

```
# Find the files by type
(Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop" -Filter '*.bat' -Recurse).FullName
# Results
<#
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\SomeBatFile.bat
#>

# Test planned action on the file to find the string pattern
(Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop" -Filter '*.bat' -Recurse).FullName | 
ForEach-Object {
    If (Select-String -Path $PSItem -Pattern 'ipconfig')
    {Remove-Item -Path $PSItem -WhatIf}
}

# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\SomeBatFile.bat".
#>


# Take action on the file to find the string pattern
(Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop" -Filter '*.bat' -Recurse).FullName | 
ForEach-Object {
    If (Select-String -Path $PSItem -Pattern 'ipconfig')
    {Remove-Item -Path $PSItem -Force -Verbose}
}
# Results
<#
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\SomeBatFile.bat".
#>

# Validate removal
(Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop" -Filter '*.bat' -Recurse).FullName
# Results
<#
No results
#>
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't cross my mind to account if there was no file containing the word. I'm getting old:(

Answer (score 0):

To search all files, use a `for` loop:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%userprofile%\desktop"
for %%a in (*.bat) do (
  type "%%a"|find /i "ipconfig" && echo del "%%a"
)
```

There is another way (looks slightly more complicated but in programmer's view is more elegant because it doesn't have to process files that don't contain the search string). This will be much faster, if there are a lot of files (and I *mean*  a *lot* of). You won't notice the speed advantage in your desktop folder though.

`findstr /m` returns not the found lines, but the filenames, where such lines were found. Put a `for /f` around to capture those filenames and delete them:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /im "ipconfig" "%userprofile%\desktop\*.bat"') do del "%%a"
```

(Note: your Desktop might be at a different location - check it)

Comment: what if its in a folder on desktop

Comment: If the folder name is known, just add it. If you want "anywhere in desktop or a subfolder, change to `findstr /sim`.

Comment: Its unknown....

Comment: and your code gives errors: %%a was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Then it's the `/s` switch in the second solution or `for /R %%a`  in the first one. Did you use it directly on the command line? Commandline syntax: `%a`, Batchfile syntax: `%%a`

Comment: I tried on batch file and command line both and how about the second command

Comment: Corrected first code snippet. Verified both. Can't replicate your `unexpected` issue. Both snippets working fine for me.

Comment: do I need to save it as .cmd or .bat?

Comment: @TheCodeExpert While there are technical differences between them, using either extension is unlikely to make a difference in this case. Both should likely be run through `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select-String` in PowerShell which allows you to search through **a** directory (*for specific file types - extensions*) allowing you to find a *pattern* match in the files filtered for:

```
$Paths = Select-String -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\*" -Include '*.bat','*.cmd' -Pattern 'ipconfig'  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path 
    if ($null -ne $Paths) {
        foreach ($Path in $Paths){
            "Match found in filepath: $Path"
            Remove-Item -Path $Path -WhatIf
        }
    }
    else {
        'No file found containing pattern'
    }
```

- *By default, Select-String finds the first match in each line and, for each match, it displays the file name, line number, and all text in the line containing the match.*
- It also allows you to use *Regex* pattern matching for more complicated tasks.

Storing the output to a variable, we can explicitly select the Full Path referencing the `Path` property. Finally, we can add some simple `if` conditions to evaluate against our variable, and using a `foreach` loop we can iterate through the capture output.

- Storing the output to a variable is necessary (*at least in this scenario*) so the file doesn't stay in use - Thank you [dave_thompson_085](https://superuser.com/users/333316/dave-thompson-085) for pointing out my mistake.

---

The draw back of using just this *cmdlet* is that, it only allows to list **a** single directory. Luckily, PowerShell can chain commands and all you would need is to slightly modify the code by using a `Get-ChildItem` with a `-Recurse` switch to allow for directory (*folder*) recursion.

```
$Paths = Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop" -Include '*.cmd','*.bat' -Recurse |
    Select-String -Pattern 'ipconfig' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path

    if ($null -ne $Paths) {
        foreach ($Path in $Paths){
            "Match found in filepath: $Path"
            Remove-Item -Path $Path -WhatIf
        }
    }
    else {
        'No file found containing pattern'
    }
```

Basically the same concept, so when you're ready, remove the `-WhatIf` *common parameter* and it will allow the removal of the file(s) found containing that pattern.

Comment: When you're ready and remove `-whatif` the `remove-item` **FAILS** because the file is in use (repeated for every file/match)

Comment: Good catch, probably helps if I actually test the code without assuming huh? lol easy enough fix. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: @dave, see my update.